# For $\mathscr{C}_1\subset\mathscr{C}$, does $X\bot Y|\mathscr{C}$ imply $X\bot Y|\mathscr{C}_1$ in the sense of conditional expecation?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose $\mathscr{C}_1\subset\mathscr{C}$ are two $\sigma$ fields, $X,Y$ are two random variables, and $E(XY|\mathscr{C})=E(X|\mathscr{C})\cdot E(Y|\mathscr{C})$, can we obtain that 
$E(XY|\mathscr{C}_1)=E(X|\mathscr{C}_1)\cdot E(Y|\mathscr{C}_1)$? And how to understand this intuitively?

This comes from a research problem. I am not sure about the answer. So I post it here for help.

---

How about if we add a condition on the random variable: suppose Y=D, where D is a binary random variable taking value of 0 and 1.

Comment: No -- Consider $(X,Y)$ uniform on $\{-1,1\}^2$, $C=\sigma(X,Y)$ and $C_1=\sigma(XY)$, then $E(XY\mid C)=XY$, $E(X\mid C)=X$, $E(Y\mid C)=Y$, $E(XY\mid C_1)=XY$ and $E(X\mid C_1)=E(Y\mid C_1)=0$.